# identifying android phone or tablet in hybrid application

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to launch my android application only in portrait mode on phones & both(portrait & landscape) on tablets. i want to identify, whether an android device is tablet or phone using phonegap. is there a way to identify it at run time?

Comment: What is a "tablet"? Do you mean a device with a larger physical screen size? Do you mean a device that lacks telephony capability? Do you mean something else?

Comment: HD phones like sony xperia z, Htc One have more resolution than Nexus 7 tablet. In this case, how can i differentiate between phones & tablets

Answer (score 0):

By checking widow size you can implement this, check the size and if size greater than (some size) take as tablet else mobile phone using javascript